# WP7 - How to set start page to external page (in library)

Tags: windows-phone-7, navigation

I am struggeling with WP7. Basically the whole navigation concept sucks, but I do not want to go into details about that. I basically threw it all away and use my own "PRISM like" navigation.

Now there is one problem which remains, I have 3 applications, all using the same infrastructure library, and taking pages from that library. The only difference between AppA and AppB is the data library loaded. 99% of the code stay the same.

What I am currently doing in the AppA is manually going to a kind of IntroPage (which basically only shows the splash screen) and then, as soon as this page is loaded, my Framework takes over and navigates to the appropriate page (trial vs. real, etc.).

Now, because of this GREAT feature of WP7 to only enable an exit on the application by navigating BACK all the way, a user who wants to leave the application has to pass the "Loading Screen" again. At least if he uses the back button. I would not mind, but I may fail marketplace rules, by showing a loading screen on "the way back"...

I tried to tell my framework "if you reach the intro page the second time, do a quick navigate back" to exit the app. Throws an exception, seems like I am not allowed to exit the app this way.

Then I tried to change the **Properties/WMAppManifest.xml** to adjust for it, trying something like this

**Name ="_default" NavigationPage="/InfrastructureLib;component/Pages/RealStartPage.xaml"**

Does not work either... Am I missing something (pretty sure its just some stupid typo again) or is what I am trying to do just not possible? **(Setting the start page of an application to a page from another library)**

If not, has anyone an idea how to tweak the App.xaml to allow the loading of custom pages from another library as start page?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is supported but you have to make a small change. In the WMAppManifest.xml, instead of
NavigationPage="/InfrastructureLib;component/Pages/RealStartPage.xaml"
use
NavigationPage="InfrastructureLib;component/Pages/RealStartPage.xaml" 
Loose the first '/' in the path. It works for me targeting WP 7.1.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question regarding setting a different page as start page:

You can remove the entry from Manifest file and call a page in another library right from App.xaml.cs. The best place will be the Launching method

```
    private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
    {
        Uri nUri = new Uri("/InfrastructureLib;component/Gui/Pages/IntroPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
        ((App)Application.Current).RootFrame.Navigate(nUri);
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, when I remove the entry from the manifest file I get a Manifest validation failure.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in that I wanted to start the application on a different page depending on saved settings. I was not able to directly set the RootFrame's Content to anything but the page named in the WMAppManifest. I tried Navigate() as previously suggested, setting the Content directly, and setting the Source. Very counter-intuitive, but nothing worked!

I finally opted to create a StartView.xaml to do the switching for me. It contains only

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage x:Class="MyApp.Views.StartView" ...>
    <ContentControl x:Name="body" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Its constructor populates the body.Content according to loaded settings.

```
public StartView() {
    InitializeComponent();

    switch (App.Current.Settings.StartPage) {
        default:      body.Content = new MainPage();  break;
        case "Other": body.Content = new OtherPage(); break;
    }
}
```

This avoids the problems you noted with Navigate(), so you don't navigate back through a dummy "Loading" page. One caveat is that (with page caching disabled), when you navigate back, the body will be populated according to the then-current Settings, which may not be the same as when the user navigated from that page. Maybe that's what you want!  If not, the problem is easily resolved using the transient PhoneApplicationService State.

Kludgy? A bit, but what do you do when what outta work doesn't work? HTH.